# Input type="file" somehow prevent the JS-made inputs' value from being sent via POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good day, as the title states, the values of the inputs created by JavaScript are not being sent via POST(or even via GET, the name of the inputs does not appear).

I managed to discover the culprit by excluding the input type="file" from the form, then trying to send it again via POST(and via GET too). Both method retrieved the values of those JS-made inputs.

**UPDATE AGAIN**

Here's the standalone culprit code:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['newEmpSubmit'])) {
        echo 'Emp Last Name '.$_POST['empLastName'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp First Name '.$_POST['empFirstName'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Middle Name '.$_POST['empMiddleName'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Address '.$_POST['empAddress'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp BirthDate '.$_POST['empBirthDate'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Nationality '.$_POST['empNationality'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Gender '.$_POST['empGender'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp SSS '.$_POST['empSSS'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp TIN '.$_POST['empTIN'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Philhealth '.$_POST['empPhilhealth'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Department '.$_POST['empDepartment'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Phone '.$_POST['empPhone'].'<br/>';

            $chosenFinal = $_POST['chosenIDFinal'];
            $chosenInfo = $_POST['chosenIDInfo'];          
            $totalIDCount = count($chosenFinal);
            for ($i=0; $i < $totalIDCount; $i++) {
                $finalChosenArray[] = $chosenFinal[$i].'('.$chosenInfo[$i].')';
            }
            $chosenIDString = implode(', ', $finalChosenArray);
        echo $chosenIDString.'<br>';
        echo 'Emp Marital Status '.$_POST['empMaritalStatus'].'<br/>';
        if ($_POST['empMaritalStatus'] == 'Married') {
            echo 'Spouse Last Name '.$_POST['spouseLastName'].'<br/>';
            echo 'Spouse First Name '.$_POST['spouseFirstName'].'<br/>';
            echo 'Spouse Middle Name '.$_POST['spouseMiddleName'].'<br/>';
            echo 'Number of children '.$_POST['numOfChildren'].'<br/>';
            echo 'Spouse Contact '.$_POST['spouseContactNo'].'<br/>';
            echo 'Spouse Address '.$_POST['spouseAddress'].'<br/>';
        }
        echo 'Emergency Last Name '.$_POST['emergencyLname'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emergency First Name '.$_POST['emergencyFname'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emergency Middle Name '.$_POST['emergencyMname'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emergency Phone '.$_POST['emergencyPhone'].'<br/>';
        echo 'relationship '.$_POST['relationship'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp qualification '.$_POST['empQualification'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Certification '.$_POST['empCertification'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Last Employer '.$_POST['empLastEmp'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Overall '.$_POST['empOverall'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Hired Date '.$_POST['hiredDate'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Salary '.$_POST['empSalary'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Salary Type '.$_POST['salaryType'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Benefits '.$_POST['empBenefits'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Tax Amount '.$_POST['empTaxAmount'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp SSS Amount '.$_POST['empSSSAmount'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Philhealth Amount '.$_POST['empPhilhealthAmount'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Status '.$_POST['empStatus'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Highest Edu '.$_POST['empHighestEdu'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Institution '.$_POST['empInstitution'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Course '.$_POST['empCourse'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Awards '.$_POST['empAwards'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Emp Grad Year '.$_POST['empGradYear'].'<br/>';
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Theme Template for Twitter Bootstrap</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js does not work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="modal fade" id="validIDModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle" style="text-align:center;">
                        VALID IDs
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="Driver's ID">
                            Driver's ID
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="Government's ID">
                            Government's ID
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="Passport ID">
                            Passport ID
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="PRC ID">
                            PRC ID
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="NBI Clearance">
                            NBI Clearance
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="Police Clearance">
                            Police Clearance
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="Postal ID">
                            Postal ID
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="Voter's ID">
                            Voter's ID
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="Brgy. Certification">
                            Brgy. Certification
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="GSIS">
                            GSI
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="Diploma">
                            Diploma
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="OWWA">
                            OWWA
                        </label>
                        <label class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chosenID[]" value="OFW ID">
                            OFW
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="addValidID()">ADD IDs</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div class="uploadimg">
                <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Upload Profile Image:<br/>
                <input type="file" name="profile_photo" />
                <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div >
                            <h3><b>ADD EMPLOYEE</b></h3>        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div >
                            <div>
                                <b>Personal Details</b>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" name="empLastName" placeholder="Last Name" required><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="empFirstName" placeholder="First Name" required><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="empMiddleName" placeholder="Middle Name" required><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="empAddress" placeholder="Residential Address" required><br/>
                                    <label for="birthDate">
                                        Birth Date
                                        <input id="birthDate" type="date" name="empBirthDate" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
                                    </label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="empNationality" placeholder="Nationality" required><br/>
                                    <input type="email" name="empEmail" placeholder="E-mail Address" required><br/>
                                    <label>
                                        Gender<br>
                                        <label >
                                            <input type="radio" name="empGender" value="Male" checked required>
                                            Male
                                        </label><br/>
                                        <label >
                                            <input type="radio" name="empGender" value="Female" required>
                                            Female
                                        </label>
                                    </label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="empSSS" placeholder="SSS Number" required><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="empTIN" placeholder="TIN Number" required><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="empPhilhealth" placeholder="PhilHealth Number" required><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="empPhone" placeholder="Phone/Contact Number" required><br/>
                                    <b>ADD VALID IDs</b>
                                    <a href="#validIDModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#validIDModal">
                                        <i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div id="validIDList" class="container-fluid">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>             
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <div >
                                <b>Family Details</b>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    Marital Status: 
                                    <select id="maritalStatusList" name="empMaritalStatus" onchange="myFunction()">
                                        <option value="Single">Single
                                        <option value="Married">Married
                                        <option value="Divorced">Separated
                                        <option value="Widowed">Widowed
                                    </select>
                                    <div id="marriedInputs">

                                    </div>
                                    Emergency Contact Information:<br/>
                                    <label for="sameCheckbox">
                                        <input id="sameCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="emergencySameSpouse" value="true" onchange="sameChecked()" disabled>
                                        Emergency Contact Same as Spouse (if present)
                                    </label><br/>
                                    <input id="relationLname" type="text" name="emergencyLname" placeholder="Last Name" required><br/>
                                    <input id="relationFname" type="text" name="emergencyFname" placeholder="First Name" required><br/>
                                    <input id="relationMname" type="text" name="emergencyMname" placeholder="Middle Name" required><br/>
                                    <input id="relationNum" type="text" name="emergencyPhone" placeholder="Phone/Contact Number" required><br/>
                                    <input id="relation" type="text" name="relationship" placeholder="Relationship To Emergency Contact" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>             
                        </div>

                        <div >
                            <div >
                                <b>Company Details</b>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" name="empQualification" placeholder="Qualification" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empCertification" placeholder="Certification" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empLastEmp" placeholder="Last Employer" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empOverall" placeholder="Overall Years of Workin Exp" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required><br>
                                    <label>
                                        Hired Date:
                                        <input  type="date" name="hiredDate" required>
                                    </label><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empCompanyID" placeholder="Employee No./ID" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empTitle" placeholder="Title" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empDepartment" placeholder="Department" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empSalary" placeholder="Salary" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required><br/>
                                    <select name="salaryType">
                                        <option value="">Salary Type</option>
                                        <option value="dailyType">Daily</option>
                                        <option value="monthlyType">Monthly</option>
                                    </select><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empBenefits" placeholder="Benefits" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empTaxAmount" placeholder="Tax Amount" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empSSSAmount" placeholder="SSS Amount" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empPhilhealthAmount" placeholder="PhilHealth Amount" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required><br>
                                    <select name="empStatus" required>
                                        <option value="">Employment Status</option>
                                        <option value="Full Time">Full Time</option>
                                        <option value="Part Time">Part Time</option>
                                        <option value="Casual">Casual</option>
                                        <option value="Fixed Term">Fixed Term</option>
                                        <option value="Shiftworker">Shiftworker</option>
                                        <option value="Probation">Probation</option>
                                        <option value="Others">Others</option>
                                    </select><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>             
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <div >
                                <b>Education Details</b>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div >
                                    <input type="text" name="empHighestEdu" placeholder="Highest Level of Education" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empInstitution" placeholder="Institution" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empCourse" placeholder="Major/Course" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empAwards" placeholder="Awards" required><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="empGradYear" placeholder="Year of Graduation" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>             
                        </div>
                        <div align="center">
                            <button type="submit" name="newEmpSubmit" class="flat-butt">ADD</button>
                    </form>
                            <a href="add_employee.php">
                                <button type="button" class="flat-butt">RESET</button>
                            </a>
                            <a href="employee.php">
                                <button type="button" class="flat-butt" >CANCEL</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script>
            function addValidID() {
                var idArray = [];
                $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){            
                    idArray.push($(this).val());
                });
                var container = document.getElementById('validIDList');
                container.innerHTML = "";
                for(var x = 0; x < idArray.length; x++) {
                    var chosenFinal = createChosenFinalInput({
                        "value": idArray[x],
                    });
                    var chosenInfo = createChosenInfoInput({
                        "placeholder": idArray[x] + " Info",
                    }, idArray[x]);

                    container.appendChild(chosenFinal);
                    container.appendChild(chosenInfo);
                }
            }
            function isNumberKey(evt){
                var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
                if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                    return false;
                return true;
            }
            function myFunction() {
                var marriedInputs = document.getElementById("marriedInputs");
                var status = document.getElementById("maritalStatusList").value;
                var sameCheckbox = document.getElementById("sameCheckbox");

                if (status == "Married") {
                    marriedInputs.appendChild(getMarriageDetailsForm());
                    sameCheckbox.disabled = false;
                } else {
                    marriedInputs.innerHTML = '';
                    sameCheckbox.disabled = true;
                    sameCheckbox.checked = false;
                }
            }

            function getMarriageDetailsForm() {
                var form = document.createElement('div');
                form.setAttribute('id', 'marriedStatusForm');

                var spouseLabel = document.createElement("LABEL");
                spouseLabel.setAttribute("id", "spouseLabelID");
                spouseLabel.for = document.getElementById("spouseLname");
                var spouseLabelText = document.createTextNode("SPOUSE: ");
                spouseLabel.appendChild(spouseLabelText);

                var spouseLnameInput = createInput({
                    "id": "spouseLname",
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "spouseLastName",
                    "placeholder": "Last Name",
                    "onkeyup": "sameChecked()",
                })

                var spouseFnameInput = createInput({
                    "id": "spouseFname",
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "spouseFirstName",
                    "placeholder": "First Name",
                    "onkeyup": "sameChecked()",
                })

                var spouseMnameInput = createInput({
                    "id": "spouseMname",
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "spouseMiddleName",
                    "placeholder": "Middle Name",
                    "onkeyup": "sameChecked()",
                });

                var childrenNumInput = createInput({
                    "id": "childrenNum",
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "numOfChildren",
                    "placeholder": "Number of Children",
                    "onkeypress": "return isNumberKey(event)",
                })

                var contactNumInput = createInput({
                    "id": "contactNum",
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "spouseContactNo",
                    "placeholder": "Contact Number",
                })

                var addressInput = createInput({
                    "id": "address",
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "spouseAddress",
                    "placeholder": "Address",
                })

                form.appendChild(spouseLabel);
                form.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                form.appendChild(spouseLnameInput);
                form.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                form.appendChild(spouseFnameInput);
                form.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                form.appendChild(spouseMnameInput);
                form.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                form.appendChild(childrenNumInput);
                form.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                form.appendChild(contactNumInput);
                form.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                form.appendChild(addressInput);
                form.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                return form;
            }
            function createInput(options) {
                var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
                input.required = true;
                for (var k in options) {
                    input.setAttribute(k, options[k]);
                }
                return input;
            }
            function createChosenFinalInput(options) {
                var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
                input.setAttribute('name', 'chosenIDFinal[]');
                for (var k in options) {
                    input.setAttribute(k, options[k]);
                }
                input.hidden = true;
                return input;
            }
            function createChosenInfoInput(options, inputLabel) {
                var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
                var label = document.createElement('LABEL');
                input.setAttribute('name', 'chosenIDInfo[]');
                input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                for (var k in options) {
                    input.setAttribute(k, options[k]);
                }
                input.required = true;
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputLabel + ":" + "\u00A0"));
                label.appendChild(input);
                return label;
            }
            function sameChecked() {
                if (sameCheckbox.checked == true) {
                    document.getElementById("relationLname").value = document.getElementById("spouseLname").value;
                    document.getElementById("relationFname").value = document.getElementById("spouseFname").value;
                    document.getElementById("relationMname").value = document.getElementById("spouseMname").value;
                    document.getElementById("relationNum").value = document.getElementById("contactNum").value;
                    document.getElementById("relationLname").readonly = true;
                    document.getElementById("relationFname").readonly = true;
                    document.getElementById("relationMname").readonly = true;
                    document.getElementById("relationNum").readonly = true;
                    document.getElementById("relation").value = "Spouse";
                    document.getElementById("relation").readonly = true;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("relationLname").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("relationFname").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("relationMname").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("relationNum").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("relation").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("relationLname").readonly = false;
                    document.getElementById("relationFname").readonly = false;
                    document.getElementById("relationMname").readonly = false;
                    document.getElementById("relationNum").readonly = false;
                    document.getElementById("relation").readonly = false;
                }
            }
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is from phpfiddle, I can't seem to link it directly, so I posted it directly here.

The initial code has the error, when you add 1 or more IDs, the chosenIDFinal will not be received by the POST.

To solve this, adjust the starting form tag just above the input for the Last Name. This is how I initially conclude that the input type="file" is the culprit. but when I just isolate the culprit and the JS-inputs, it works. So I'm confused as to what is the real culprit

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: have you put enctype="multipar/form-data" in your form?

Comment: @Araz i have that in the form

Comment: @Rayon I'll try

Comment: you dont get the $_FILES[] value in the php o you send via $.ajax

Comment: @Araz you mean that I must process/get/store the $_FILES[] so that the values will appear?

Comment: (0) Where's the form? (1) No need to use the `for` attribute of a label if it wraps the element it's for. (2) There's no problem creating, filling and submitting a form (just) with javascript - to know where you're going wrong, you should present the smallest code snippet required to reproduce the problem. SO isn't really the place to expect your audience to guess.

Comment: I updated the post, I have a slow connection, I can't provide neither a snippet nor create an account in JSFiddle, that's why I just post the codes here. I'm very sorry for the inconveniences this post caused. In the main code, when I include the culprit, POST or GET can't get the values of the JS inputs only, when I remove the culprit, it works. But when I isolate just the culprit and the JS inputs, it works.

Comment: Maybe the culprit isn't really the input type="file", I'll try removing the other inputs(not included in the post because it's really long, but those are only inputs for employee registration) one by one, hoping to find another culprit. But i hope someone can narrow me down to some possible culprits for this kind of problem.

Comment: @CarlJanBinalla - no inconvenience caused, don't fret! :) For what it's worth - you don't need an account at jsfiddle to create fiddles - though you do lose certain functionality. Something that may be worth looking for, is improperly closed tags - though I can't see how you'd get these if creating using the object model in javascript (rather than simple string concatenation). I'll keep thinking. :)

Comment: I've updated the post to show the problem code, I don't know how to link the phpfiddle here, so I posted the codes here